# Asynchronous task execution using Spring in container managed environment

Tags: spring, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool, spring-webflow

I want to run few tasks asynchronously in a web application. My question is which Spring implementation of task executors i should use in a Container managed environment.

I refereed to [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) chapter in Spring documentation and found few options.

One option I considered is **WorkManagerTaskExecutor**. This is very simple and works seamlessly with the IBM Websepher server which I'm currently using but this is very specific to IBM Websphere and Oracle Weblogic servers. I don't want to tie my code specifically to one particular implementation as in some test and local regions we are using Jetty container & this implementation creates problems to run the code in Jetty.

Other  options like **SimpleThreadPoolTaskExecutor**  does not seem to be best fit to leverage thread pooling in container managed environment and I don't want to create new thread myself.

Could you pleas suggest how do I go about this. Any pointers to a sample implementation will be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, it depends. If you rely on the container's thread management and want to be able to set thread pools on its admin interface or if you're application is not the only app inside the container or you use specific features like setting thread pool priorities for EJB or JMS you should add support for the WorkManagerTaskExecutor and make it configurable. If not, you can use whatever you want cause in the end threads are just threads. Since Spring is an IOC container you can do it. To use the same app everywhere I wouldn't suggest to change the XML config per app version. Rather

1. use [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) with [configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) to set the executor type and inside your java config return the proper bean type. If you use Jetty you should have a configuration for the thread pool sizes to to be able to tune it.
2. use [spring boot like auto configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html) which usually rely on available classes on classpath (@ConditionalOnClass). If your weblogic or websphere specific classes are available or any other container specific thing like env variables you can create the WorkManagerTaskExecutor

With both of these you can deploy the same war everywhere.